# Get phone carrier using WP7.1 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Is there any way to get the phone carrier using WP7.1 SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202875%28v=vs.92%29.aspx you can get it from DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator

e.g.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

     sb.Append("Mobile operator:  ");
     sb.AppendLine(DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator);

     MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
 }
```